# Is "int a;" a declaration or definition in C and in C++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, declaration

Is `int a;` a declaration or definition in C? Is there any difference in C++?

I was always thinking it's just a declaration, until today...

Is it a declaration or a definition?

Answer (score 20):

A *declaration* describes an object, whereas a *definition* requests the creation of an object.  All *definitions* are also *declarations*, but the reverse is not true.

In the case of `int a;`, what it is depends on where it is placed in the source code:

- Within a function, `int a;` is a definition - it requests the creation of an `int` variable with automatic storage duration (and of course also a declaration);
- At file scope, the answer is different in C and C++.  In C, `int a;` is a *tentative definition* (of which there can be more than one, as long as the types and linkage are agreeable); in C++, it is an ordinary definition with external linkage.
- Within a `struct` or `union` specifier, `int a;` is a declaration of a member.

Comment: is function and class extern by default?

Comment: Comment to the last bullet: in C++, `int a;` as a member declaration within a class specifier is a definition.

Comment: I mean `void func(); class T(); ` are they extern?

Comment: @lex: Yes, external linkage is the default for file-scope identifiers.

Comment: Note that strictly, ISO C90 (ANSI C89) and C99 (§6.9/5 'External Definitions') both require a single definition across all translation units, so only one TU may have a tentative definition and all other TUs should have external declarations.  However, Annex J of the C99 standard recognizes the 'common definition' approach (where more than one TU may have a tentative definition as long as at most one has an initialized definition) as one of the possible extensions and it is, in fact, widely supported on Unix systems (and quite possibly elsewhere too).

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, but `static int a;` is a definition in namespace scope or within a function, but a non-defining declaration within class scope.  And it gets worse: `const static int a = 42;` is a definition even in class scope.

Comment: @Ben `static int a` is not `int a`. I was only saying that about non-static data members. Also, your last statement is not correct. `const static int a = 42` is not a definition when it appears in class scope. It's still a declaration only.

Comment: @Johannes: Guess you're right, I had misunderstood the new rule about inline initialization of const static members of integral type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Interestingly, the "common definition" approach is now less widely supported than it once was - `-fno-common` is now the default in the latest versions of both gcc and clang (see for example https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85678)

Comment: @caf — yeah, especially since GCC 10.x makes the `-fno-vommon` the default.  It is closer to the C++ requirements as implemented by G++, though.  It is making extra work for me on a system that (ab)used common definitions.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what "tentative" means?

Comment: @user129393192: You can have more than one *tentative definition* of an identifier, and they'll just act like declarations except that if there is no other file-scope definition of the identifier in the file, it'll act like the identifier was defined at file scope with a zero initialiser.

Answer (score 7):

Where does it appear in your program?

In most contexts, it is both a declaration and definition.

OTOH, `extern int a;` is a declaration only.

Comment: At file scope, `int a;` is a declaration and a tentative definition.

Comment: @caf: you should post that as an answer. It's the tricky case most people don't get.

Comment: is function and class extern by default?

Comment: @caf: in C. The difference in C++ is that there's no such thing as a tentative definition, objects can be defined once and that's it. 6.9.2/1 of C99 vs. C.1.2 of C++03.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
int a;
```

It's a definition as well as a declaration.

Consider the following example...

```
int i;
printf("%d", i);
```

Some junk value will be printed. Which obviously means it's got a memory location.

If you want to just declare a variable and not define it then go for "extern" keyword.

Thus `extern int b;` is just a declaration and not a definition.

Example:

```
extern int var;
int main(void)
{
    var = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Thus the above program will throw an error as "var" was not defined anywhere.