# Declaration vs definition for a variable

Tags: c++

Referring to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326873/10736710,

I think following should hold true:

```
int x; //declaration
int y = 2; //definition
```

But looks like first is definition and not declaration. Can someone comment how first is a definition?

Comment: What about the linked answer do you not understand?

Comment: how `int x` is definition and not a just declaration.

Comment: @srt2334red it is a definition because it defines `x`.

Comment: Isn't first declare `x` and second one defines (makes it ready to use in implementation)?

Comment: `int x` is a *definition* because it calls the default constructor for the `int` type.

Comment: @Marc.2377 built-in types do not have constructors

Comment: See also: [Is “int a;” a declaration or definition in C and in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4476169/3258851)

Comment: The linked post contains what you're asking. I don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @M.M Well, technically yes, but: OP should see [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113365/3258851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition**: when you define something it takes up actual memory in your program. When you do `int x;` you already take up memory for your variable even it is unitialized.

**Initialization**: initializing something can only be done while defining it simultaniously. The variable will already have a valid value assigned to it after creating it. E.g. `int x = 3;` `x` is now initialized and defined.

**Declaration**: If you declare something it does not really take up memory in your application like for example function prototypes. If your declare a function like this `void foo();` it is just an introduction for the compiler and unless you define it, will not take up memory in your application.

**Assignement**: you assign a variable whenever you set its value after you defined it. So if you do

```
int x;
x = 2;
```

You assigned `x` the value 2

Comment: I think the question is about the declaration at namespace scope

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot okay nvm he accepted the answer so it seems to be helpful

Comment: if he understood the wrong thing, it defeat the purpose of answering

Comment: Note that technically, `int x;` *is* initialization. It is syntax for *default* initialization, which in case of `int` results in an indeterminate value (behaviour of the program is undefined if an indeterminate value is used). But, "uninitialized" is colloquially used for this situation, so I won't blame you for it. Also note that if the declaration is in the namespace scope, then the variable has static storage duration and therefore it would in fact be zero initialized rather than default initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The standard (draft) says:

> [basic.def]
>
> Each entity declared by a declaration is also defined by that
>   declaration unless:
>
> - (2.1) it declares a function without specifying the function's body ([dcl.fct.def]),wrong
> - (2.2) it contains the extern specifier or a linkage-specification20 ([dcl.link]) and neither an initializer nor a function-body,
> - (2.3) it declares a non-inline static data member in a class definition ([class.mem], [class.static]),
> - (2.4) it declares a static data member outside a class definition and the variable was defined within the class with the constexpr
>     specifier (this usage is deprecated; see [depr.static_constexpr]),
> - (2.5) it is introduced by an elaborated-type-specifier ([class.name]),
> - (2.6) it is an opaque-enum-declaration ([dcl.enum]),
> - (2.7) it is a template-parameter ([temp.param]),
> - (2.8) it is a parameter-declaration ([dcl.fct]) in a function declarator that is not the declarator of a function-definition,
> - (2.9) it is a typedef declaration,
> - (2.10) it is an alias-declaration ([dcl.typedef]),
> - (2.11) it is a using-declaration ([namespace.udecl]),
> - (2.12) it is a deduction-guide ([temp.deduct.guide]),
> - (2.13) it is a static_assert-declaration ([dcl.dcl]),
> - (2.14) it is an attribute-declaration ([dcl.dcl]),
> - (2.15) it is an empty-declaration ([dcl.dcl]),
> - (2.16) it is a using-directive ([namespace.udir]),
> - (2.17) it is an explicit instantiation declaration, or
> - (2.18) it is an explicit specialization whose declaration is not a definition.

The declaration `int x;` isn't any of the listed exceptions, so it is a definition.

> But looks like first is definition and not declaration.

It is correct that `int x;` is a definition as shown by the quoted rule, but it is technically wrong to say that it isn't a declaration - all definitions are declarations. You *could* say that it isn't *merely* a declaration, or you could say that it isn't a *forward* declaration.

Comment: While correct, I highly doubt this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @PasserBy it's not really clear to me what OP is looking for. The answer to "how is `int x;` a definition?" is in fact "because the standard says it is"